# Synaptic touchpad on laptop not working

Tags: touchpad

I'm using a laptop with built-in touch-pad that works in Windows 7. But after I switched to Ubuntu 12.04 LTS, it's not working now.

Comment: can you check whether it is on? more info here: http://askubuntu.com/questions/257035/how-do-i-fix-the-mouse-after-pairing-with-bluetooth/260850#260850

Comment: I have enable it, but it's still not working.

Comment: I had a similar issue on 12.04.02. Press Ctrl+Alt+T to open a terminal and paste those commands to check if they solve your problem: `sudo modprobe -r psmouse && sudo modprobe psmouse proto=imps`

Comment: @Salem please turn your comment info an answer..

Answer (score 65, accepted):

This seems to be a [bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/xserver-xorg-input-synaptics/+bug/1096046) in 12.04.2. As stated in comments, a simple fix would be unloading the mouse driver and load it again like this:

```
sudo modprobe -r psmouse
sudo modprobe psmouse proto=imps
```

This only keeps the touchpad working on this session. To make it permanent one can create a file like `/etc/modprobe.d/psmouse.conf` (you can choose the name you want, but you must keep the extension) with the following content:

```
options psmouse proto=imps
```

Comment: Yess! Had same problem and using Google came here and this solution worked. Thanks!

Comment: This still happens in 14.04 but this fix still fixes it although I can't get it to execute on start of the machine so I am currently stuck running it manually each time...

Comment: This just helped years late on Ubuntu 15.10

Comment: 2016 still same bug and this fixed it

Comment: I came across this error after upgrading from 16.04 to 17.04.

Comment: I came across this issue upgrading from 16.04 to 18.04 on a Dell XPS 13. However: The edit to add psmouse.conf does not work, the fix does not stick after a reboot.

Comment: Had the same issue with 18.04 on Dell XPS 13. Unloading psmouse removes scrolling and stuff though :(