# How do I get the touchpad working on a Toshiba P850?

Tags: installation, dual-boot, 64-bit, touchpad

The synaptics touchpad is not working after a fresh install of ubuntu 12.04.2 on a Toshiba P850.  It works fine under windows 8 (it's a dual boot machine).

It appears to be recognised OK in Xorg.0.log

I tried the proposed solution in the linked question:

```
sudo modprobe -r psmouse && sudo modprobe psmouse proto=imps
```

..but this does not work.

This message gets logged to syslog but the touchpad is still unresponsive:

```
Apr 28 20:01:36 foobar kernel: [  256.386831] input: PS/2 Synaptics TouchPad as /devices/platform/i8042/serio1/input/input17
```

#### Edit

This is not a duplicate of:

- [Synaptic touchpad on laptop not working](https://askubuntu.com/questions/262287/synaptic-touchpad-on-laptop-not-working)

I have read all related posts I can find but none of them offer a solution.

The touchpad is detected but does not work.  It works in Windows 8 (machine is dual boot)

```
$ egrep -i touchpad syslog
May 18 20:44:35 node7 kernel: [   10.787917] psmouse serio1: synaptics: Touchpad model: 1, fw: 8.1, id: 0x1e2b1, caps: 0xd00123/0x840300/0x126c00
May 18 20:44:35 node7 kernel: [   10.893065] input: SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad as /devices/platform/i8042/serio1/input/input10
May 19 09:24:36 node7 kernel: [   11.728268] psmouse serio1: synaptics: Touchpad model: 1, fw: 8.1, id: 0x1e2b1, caps: 0xd00123/0x840300/0x126c00
May 19 09:24:36 node7 kernel: [   11.861941] input: SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad as /devices/platform/i8042/serio1/input/input12
May 19 09:36:21 node7 kernel: [   11.646728] psmouse serio1: synaptics: Touchpad model: 1, fw: 8.1, id: 0x1e2b1, caps: 0xd00123/0x840300/0x126c00
May 19 09:36:21 node7 kernel: [   11.776112] input: SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad as /devices/platform/i8042/serio1/input/input11
```

In particular this does not work, it just causes compiz to crash and restart:

```
$ sudo modprobe -r psmouse
$ sudo modprobe psmouse proto=imps
May 19 09:48:12 node7 rsyslogd: [origin software="rsyslogd" swVersion="5.8.6" x-pid="1101" x-info="http://www.rsyslog.com"] rsyslogd was HUPed
May 19 09:48:42 node7 rsyslogd: last message repeated 2 times
May 19 09:49:41 node7 gnome-session[2106]: WARNING: Application 'compiz.desktop' killed by signal
May 19 09:49:41 node7 gnome-session[2106]: WARNING: App 'compiz.desktop' respawning too quickly
May 19 09:49:41 node7 gnome-session[2106]: CRITICAL: We failed, but the fail whale is dead. Sorry....
May 19 09:49:50 node7 anacron[1249]: Job `cron.daily' terminated
May 19 09:49:50 node7 anacron[1249]: Normal exit (1 job run)
May 19 09:50:09 node7 kernel: [  844.392522] input: PS/2 Synaptics TouchPad as /devices/platform/i8042/serio1/input/input16
May 19 09:50:51 node7 kernel: [  886.068210] type=1400 audit(1368953451.556:35): apparmor="DENIED" operation="capable" parent=1 profile="/usr/sbin/cupsd" pid=1194 comm="cupsd" pid=1194 comm="cupsd" capability=36  capname="block_suspend"
```

Comment: See if [this](http://askubuntu.com/a/262364/33871) helps.

Comment: It doesn't help I'm afraid, it just crashes compiz

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue is now resolved since a recent Ubuntu update.  Not sure which update it was but thanks guys & girls :)