# Synaptics error "no touchpad found" at startup on HP laptop

Tags: touchpad, kde, startup, synaptics, modprobe

I know there are a lot of topics on the synaptics touchpad not working, but I can't seem to find the answer to my problem anywhere. Please forgive me if I missed it.

Here is what happened.
After using the "ambient light" F11 key on my HP laptop (Compaq nc8430), the touchpad was disabled and I couldn't get it to work.
Then I found this thread : "[Synaptic touchpad on laptop not working](https://askubuntu.com/questions/262287/synaptic-touchpad-on-laptop-not-working)". And Salem's answer totally solved my problem, both for the session fix and for the permanent fix.

But since then, after each reboot I get the same error pop-up, with the following content:

> No touchpad found.
>   No touchpad was found in this system. If the
>   system has a touchpad, please make sure that the synaptics driver is
>   properly installed and configured.
>   If your touchpad is not found,
>   though the driver is installed and configured correctly, please
>   compile detailed information about your touchpad hardware and report
>   this issue to the issue tracker.

Needless to say, the driver is indeed installed, activated and configured (even though it's kind of useless now, since I guess the .conf file I created is doing all the work).
I know it's a minor issue, because the touchpad does work properly, but it's getting really annoying...

So, could anyone please help me fix this error pop-up problem ? Thank you !

**EDIT**: After trying unsuccessfully everything below following Saurav's advice, my popup problem is still there.
To be clear, my touchpad *does* work perfectly since the fix I mentionned above. But the fix itself, namely the `.conf` file in `modprobe.d`, seems to be causing the error "No touchpad found".
So, is there anything I can do to prevent this confusion, for example a command to add in that `.conf` file ?
Or does anyone know of *another* method entirely to fix my touchpad permanently *and* not get a false error of missing touchpad?
Thanks again.

Comment: Hi, I did start my message with "Hello everyone", but I must have deleted it inadvertently before posting... I tried to edit afterwards, but it doesn't show ; sorry, I'm new here.

Comment: Try to re-configure these packages once by following commands: `sudo dpkg-reconfigure xserver-xorg-input-multitouch` , `sudo dpkg-reconfigure xserver-xorg-input-synpatics` and `sudo dpkg-reconfigure $(dpkg -l | grep xserver | awk '{print $2}' | tr '\n' ' '` and `sudo update-initramfs -u`. Restart your system once..

Comment: Wow that was fast, thanks.  I just tried that, but it doesn't work, it says that the packages `xserver-xorg-input-multitouch`and `xserver-xorg-input-synaptics` are not installed and that no information is available.

Comment: That is what I was guessing.. Try to install these packages, probably after installation your problem would be solved.. You can install it by: `sudo apt-get install xserver-xorg-input-synaptics xserver-xorg-input-multitouch`. Read the installation message carefully, i,e don't remove any other package while installation. Once installed execute this: `sudo update-initramfs -u` and restart your system. Reply..

Comment: So, I installed the 2 packages and it seemed to have worked properly. I then used the `update-initramfs` command and rebooted, but the error pop-up was still there.  So I used the `dpkg-reconfigure` of you first message and it worked for the `multitouch` and `synaptics` ones. But I'm confused about the following command, it then opens a new line with only the `>` sign. Sorry, I know almost nothing about console commands, so I can't correct it myself...

Comment: Oho my mistake! I forgot to close the `)` parenthesis.. :O so your command will be: `sudo dpkg-reconfigure $(dpkg -l | grep xserver | awk '{print $2}' | tr '\n' ' ')`. If it runs successfully then execute this command also : `sudo dpkg-reconfigure -a` (it would take some time, so please wait). It will not give any error and will execute successfully. After this please follow my first comment. Reply..

Comment: Ok thanks, the first command seemed to have run properly; it ended with `ldconfig deferred processing now taking place`, is that OK?  Then I launched the `sudo dpkg-reconfigure -a` command, and I have no idea what I was doing, but I accepted every default setting in the graphical dialogue interface... It ended with this message: `/usr/sbin/dpkg-reconfigure: initramfs-tools is broken or not fully installed`. Is it OK and should I proceed with the `sudo update-initramfs -u` command?

Comment: `/usr/sbin/dpkg-reconfigure: initramfs-tools is broken or not fully installed` this message tells that `initramfs-tools` is either not installed or broken. You can re-install it by : `sudo apt-get -f install --reinstall initramfs-tools`. Once installed successfully run this command: `sudo update-initramfs -u`  Uff!! It is going to be lengthy now.. :P

Comment: Just so you know, as the `sudo update-initramfs -u` doesn't send any error at all though, I decided to be optimistic and tried one last time all of your first post actions (with the corrections); but the error pop-up is till there after rebooting.  So I guess I'll re-install the `initramfs-tools` now as you said!

Comment: Did `sudo update-initramfs -u` display any message like: `update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-3.11.0-031100-generic` If not then really you've to re-install it.

Comment: Yes, it did say that each time (with the different numbers `img-3.8.0-29` but I suppose it doesn't matter). I used the `reinstall` command anyway, followed once again by the `update` one, and there was no error apparently. Now what, reboot, or some more commands?

Comment: finally once more `sudo dpkg-reconfigure -a` because it was not successfully executed last time. Then `sudo update-initramfs -u` then restart.

Comment: Also, it may be stupid, but now that you made me fix a lot of things, should I delete the `/etc/modprobe.d/psmouse.conf` file that I mentioned I created? Does it not create some conflict?

Comment: Instead of deleting take it as backup like: `sudo mv /etc/modprobe.d/psmouse.conf /etc/modprobe.d/psmouse.conf_bak` Yes you can give it a try.. 
R

Comment: Well, you're not gonna like it: I ran `sudo dpkg-reconfigure -a` and I got the same message at the end `/usr/sbin/dpkg-reconfigure: initramfs-tools is broken or not fully installed`... Is there anything I did wrong in the dialogue interface or somewhere else?  I'm really sorry to keep bothering you!

Comment: Pretty strange! Did you recently install some new kernel? I tried almost everything, last thing I would like to suggest you is to install `gsynaptics`; `sudo apt-get install gsynaptics`. I also suggest you to install [Touch-pad applet indicator](http://www.maketecheasier.com/10-must-have-indicator-applets-for-ubuntu-12-04) **6th** point. Find how to install and how it works. gsynaptics will help you to configure **touchpad** locally. You have to Open **Pointing Devices** (search in dash). Hope these would help you any how. Reply..

Comment: I use KDE, isn't `gsynaptics` for Gnome only? I didn't install any new kernel ; as of today, I have a notification for a new Kubuntu version update, but I haven't accepted it yet.  Also, in the meantime, I did "remove" my .conf file as you said, and on reboot the error pop-up was gone, but then again so was my touchpad...So I believe the error definitely comes from there (I followed again the procedure of the thread I mentioned in my orginal post and touchpad is back now as usual). Isn't there anything else I can write in that file for example, to prevent it from generating the error?

Comment: I didn't know that you were using **KDE**. And I really don't know whether you can use `gsynaptics` in KDE or not. If you are able to open **Pointing Devices** then I think you can install it. Sorry! I don't know how to fix that error message. Although it is now clear that `.conf` file was causing it. All I can do is only wish you good luck that you don't get the error again. :) Sandra, I found [this link](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2066717), it seems to be the same issue. Please give it a look.

Comment: I think the equivalent of `gsynaptics` for KDE is `synaptiks`, which I have. Also, if I understood correctly what was done in the thread I mentionned, I think my touchpad is now recognized as a PS-Mouse, and not as a touchpad _per se_, so it's logical that there is "no touchpad found". Thank you for the link though, I'm going to read it carefully (but as it's quite long, I wanted to answer you before).

Comment: @Saurav  Well, that link you just gave doesn't seem to be helping with my problem, too bad ; I'll keep looking and trying...  Anyway, thank you so much for spending such a long time helping me! Is there anything I can do to improve your "_reputation_" or something? (again, I'm new here..).

Comment: Ha ha no need for that :) I am so glad to help you although it didn't make any sense. It worth more that reputation :P for your knowledge: If I had really helped you and posted an answer then only you would have been able to accept my answer which would have increased my reputation.. Thanks for believing me and for following the instructions patiently. :D