# dell 5537 Touchpad not working (Ubuntu 14.04)

Tags: 14.04, dell, touchpad

after upgrading my new ubuntu from 12.04 to 14.04 I found out that touchpad is not working. Strange thing is that it seems to be detected, as:

```
cat /proc/bus/input/devices
```

gives

```
I: Bus=0011 Vendor=0002 Product=0007 Version=01b1
N: Name="SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad"
P: Phys=isa0060/serio1/input0
S: Sysfs=/devices/platform/i8042/serio1/input/input5
U: Uniq=
H: Handlers=mouse1 event5 
B: PROP=1
B: EV=b
B: KEY=e520 30000 0 0 0 0
B: ABS=660800011000003
```

and also

```
xinput
```

gives

```
⎡ Virtual core pointer                        id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                  id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ USB Multi-Smart Mouse                       id=9    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad                  id=12    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎣ Virtual core keyboard                       id=3    [master keyboard (2)]
    ↳ Virtual core XTEST keyboard                 id=5    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                                id=6    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Video Bus                                   id=7    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                                id=8    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Laptop_Integrated_Webcam_HD                 id=10    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ AT Translated Set 2 keyboard                id=11    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Dell WMI hotkeys                            id=13    [slave  keyboard (3)]
```

also details of touchpad in xinput look fine:

```
xinput --watch-props 12
```

gives

```
Device 'SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad':
    Device Enabled (134):    1
    Coordinate Transformation Matrix (136):    1.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 1.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 1.000000
    Device Accel Profile (263):    0
    Device Accel Constant Deceleration (264):    1.000000
    Device Accel Adaptive Deceleration (265):    1.000000
    Device Accel Velocity Scaling (266):    10.000000
    Device Product ID (253):    2, 7
    Device Node (254):    "/dev/input/event5"
    Evdev Axis Inversion (267):    0, 0
    Evdev Axis Calibration (268):    <no items>
    Evdev Axes Swap (269):    0
    Axis Labels (270):    "Abs MT Position X" (288), "Abs MT Position Y" (289), "Abs MT Pressure" (290), "Abs Tool Width" (287), "None" (0), "None" (0), "None" (0)
    Button Labels (271):    "Button Left" (137), "Button Unknown" (256), "Button Right" (139), "Button Wheel Up" (140), "Button Wheel Down" (141)
    Evdev Middle Button Emulation (272):    0
    Evdev Middle Button Timeout (273):    50
    Evdev Third Button Emulation (274):    0
    Evdev Third Button Emulation Timeout (275):    1000
    Evdev Third Button Emulation Button (276):    3
    Evdev Third Button Emulation Threshold (277):    20
    Evdev Wheel Emulation (278):    0
    Evdev Wheel Emulation Axes (279):    0, 0, 4, 5
    Evdev Wheel Emulation Inertia (280):    10
    Evdev Wheel Emulation Timeout (281):    200
    Evdev Wheel Emulation Button (282):    4
    Evdev Drag Lock Buttons (283):    0
```

it`s worth mentioning that external mouse works correctly. Also, in window "Settings>Mouse and touchpad" there are no settings for touchpad, only speed of double click regulation.

I would be grateful for any help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

found the solution myself.  [this was helpful](https://askubuntu.com/a/262364/293492). it turned out that psmouse missed some options on loading. Also, I found out that packages `xserver-xorg-input-synaptics` and `gpointing-device-settings` were missing. I installed them

```
sudo apt-get install xserver-xorg-input-synaptics gpointing-device-settings
```

now I can configure my touchpad from GUI.

everything works now so please mark this as solved