# Dell Inspiron 1520 touchpad buttons not detected on ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, dell, touchpad

I recently installed Ubuntu 14.04 on my laptop Dell Inspiron 1520. After installation, touchpad was detected but Vertical & Horizontal scrolling and Left & Right click were not working. So I tweaked the synclient configuration using the command

```
synclient -l
```

and figured out that scroll functionality was disabled, so enabled it. I tried a lot, but I could not find a way to enable the right and left click buttons. [My laptop's touchpad is same as the image in the url.](http://www.notebookcheck.net/fileadmin/_migrated/pics/dell_inspiron_1520_touchpad_08.jpg)

Output of `xinput`

```
$ xinput
⎡ Virtual core pointer                              id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                    id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad                    id=14   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ Logitech Unifying Device. Wireless PID:400a   id=17   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎣ Virtual core keyboard                     id=3    [master keyboard (2)]
↳ Virtual core XTEST keyboard               id=5    [slave  keyboard (3)]
↳ Video Bus                                 id=6    [slave  keyboard (3)]
↳ Power Button                              id=7    [slave  keyboard (3)]
↳ Sleep Button                              id=8    [slave  keyboard (3)]
↳ Dell Dell USB Keyboard                    id=11   [slave  keyboard (3)]
↳ Laptop Integrated Webcam                  id=12   [slave  keyboard (3)]
↳ AT Translated Set 2 keyboard              id=13   [slave  keyboard (3)]
↳ Dell WMI hotkeys                          id=15   [slave  keyboard (3)]
↳ HD Webcam C525                            id=16   [slave  keyboard (3)]
```

Output of `xinput watch-props 14`

```
$ xinput watch-props 14
Device 'SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad':
Device Enabled (152):   1
Coordinate Transformation Matrix (154): 1.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 1.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 1.000000
Device Accel Profile (273): 1
Device Accel Constant Deceleration (274):   2.500000
Device Accel Adaptive Deceleration (275):   1.000000
Device Accel Velocity Scaling (276):    12.500000
Synaptics Edges (296):  1752, 5192, 1620, 4236
Synaptics Finger (297): 25, 30, 0
Synaptics Tap Time (298):   180
Synaptics Tap Move (299):   221
Synaptics Tap Durations (300):  180, 180, 100
Synaptics ClickPad (301):   0
Synaptics Middle Button Timeout (302):  75
Synaptics Two-Finger Pressure (303):    282
Synaptics Two-Finger Width (304):   7
Synaptics Scrolling Distance (305): 255, 5
Synaptics Edge Scrolling (306): 0, 0, 0
Synaptics Two-Finger Scrolling (307):   1, 1
Synaptics Move Speed (308): 1.000000, 1.750000, 0.039809, 0.000000
Synaptics Off (309):    2
Synaptics Locked Drags (310):   0
Synaptics Locked Drags Timeout (311):   5000
Synaptics Tap Action (312): 2, 3, 0, 0, 1, 3, 0
Synaptics Click Action (313):   1, 1, 0
Synaptics Circular Scrolling (314): 0
Synaptics Circular Scrolling Distance (315):    0.100000
Synaptics Circular Scrolling Trigger (316): 0
Synaptics Circular Pad (317):   0
Synaptics Palm Detection (318): 0
Synaptics Palm Dimensions (319):    10, 200
Synaptics Coasting Speed (320): 20.000000, 50.000000
Synaptics Pressure Motion (321):    30, 160
Synaptics Pressure Motion Factor (322): 1.000000, 1.000000
Synaptics Resolution Detect (323):  1
Synaptics Grab Event Device (324):  1
Synaptics Gestures (325):   1
Synaptics Capabilities (326):   1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1
Synaptics Pad Resolution (327): 109, 73
Synaptics Area (328):   0, 0, 0, 0
Synaptics Noise Cancellation (329): 25, 25
Device Product ID (269):    2, 7
Device Node (270):  "/dev/input/event6"
Property 'Synaptics Off' changed.
Synaptics Off (309):    0
```

Please help me figure this out.

Comment: doesn't it work, or does the scrolling work as two finger scrolling?

Comment: @gio900 Scrolling works fine, I have problem with left and right click buttons, they are not detected and thus not working.

Comment: maybe this will help: http://askubuntu.com/questions/483229/dell-5537-touchpad-not-working-ubuntu-14-04

Comment: @gio900 I tried the things mentioned in that link, That helped me solve the scrolling problem. But I still have the right click and left click button issues.

Comment: please: `xinput` and then `xinput --watch-props n` as n you have to put the id of the touchpad device.

Comment: @gio900 I updated the question with outputs of `xinput` & `xinput watch-props 14`

Answer (score 0):

no warranty, but digging the net, your problem look like related to xorg.conf

I shall try that:

`sudo apt-get install xserver-xorg-input-synaptics`

`sudo gedit /etc/X11/xorg.conf`

then add:

```
# **********************************************************************
# Modules section. This allows modules to be specified
# **********************************************************************

Section "Module"
       Load  "synaptics"
EndSection


# ******************************
# Files section
# ******************************

Section "Files"
       ModulePath   "/usr/lib/xorg/modules"
EndSection

# ******************************
# Core Pointer's InputDevice section
# ******************************

Section "InputDevice"
       Identifier      "USB Mouse"
       Driver          "mouse"
       Option          "Device"                "/dev/input/mice"
       Option       "SendCoreEvents"    "true"
       Option          "Protocol"              "IMPS/2"
       Option          "ZAxisMapping"          "4 5"
       Option          "Buttons"               "5"
EndSection

Section "InputDevice"
       Identifier      "Touchpad"
       Driver          "synaptics"
       Option  "Device"        "/dev/input/mouse0"
       Option  "Protocol"      "auto-dev"
       Option  "LeftEdge"      "1700"
       Option  "RightEdge"     "5300"
       Option  "TopEdge"       "1700"
       Option  "BottomEdge"    "4200"
       Option  "FingerLow"     "25"
       Option  "FingerHigh"    "30"
       Option  "MaxTapTime"    "180"
       Option  "MaxTapMove"    "220"
       Option  "VertScrollDelta" "100"
       Option  "MinSpeed"      "0.06"
       Option  "MaxSpeed"      "0.12"
       Option  "AccelFactor" "0.0010"
       Option  "SHMConfig"     "on"
EndSection
```

as find here: https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Dell_Inspiron_1520

then restart X (that last command will bring you to the login gdm, so save what are you doing before!):

`sudo restart lightdm`

http://ubuntuportal.com/2012/05/restart-x-server-ubuntu-12-04-without-rebooting.html

Let me know if it work :)

Comment: I tried it, unfortunately that didn't solve the problem.

Comment: sorry, no better idea :/

Comment: ehm... we forgot lo load modules, as done in the wiki... I just edit

Comment: No help, still the problem persists. I tried to log the click events on both right and left click buttons and I could not find any log corresponding to those buttons.