# Synaptic touchpad on laptop not working after update

Tags: 12.04, kernel, touchpad, synaptics, modprobe

I have found this solution from a thread a while ago but its temporary fix only:

> This seems to be a
>   [bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/xserver-xorg-input-synaptics/+bug/1096046)
>   in 12.04.2. As stated in comments, a simple fix would be unloading the
>   mouse driver and load it again like this:
>
> ```
> sudo modprobe -r psmouse
> sudo modprobe psmouse proto=imps
> ```
>
> This only keeps the touchpad working on this session. To make it
>   permanent one can create a file like `/etc/modprobe.d/psmouse.conf`
>   (you can choose the name you want, but you must keep the extension)
>   with the following content:
>
> ```
> options psmouse proto=imps
> ```

~~ [Salem](https://askubuntu.com/users/33871/salem)'s [answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/262364/22949) to [Synaptic touchpad on laptop not working](https://askubuntu.com/questions/262287/synaptic-touchpad-on-laptop-not-working)

My question is how to make a permanent file like he was talking about. I don't have any idea how to do that in Ubuntu.

That answer (`sudo modprobe -r psmouse &&
sudo modprobe psmouse proto=imps`) works on my 12.04 system but after I have shut down my laptop the weird problem comes back. I don't really know how to make the solution permanent because what he said was that it is just a temporary fix.

Comment: Cheers sir @Eliah hehe~~

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Open a Terminal by type <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>

Copy and paste this

```
echo "options psmouse proto=imps" | sudo tee /etc/modprobe.d/psmouse.conf
```

Enter your password, and you should be good to go.

Comment: Sir after i hit my password i don't see any progress and when i try to exit the terminal it says that there is a process running..How would i know if its done or if its really processing?Does it really takes time?Thanks~ @ElefantPhace

Comment: `ls /etc/modprobe.d/ | grep psmouse` should output `psmouse.conf`and no it takes no time at all. What process does it say is still running?

Comment: here's what i did i typed the echo "options psmouse proto=imps" then it shows:                                             options psmouse proto=imps                                            Afterwards i typed the sudo tee /etc/modprobe.d/psmouse.conf then i entered my password then nothing follows it shows nothing and when i try to close it, it says theres still process running but i dont know which process was that says still running.. Im confused xD

Comment: Close that terminal and start over. Don't separate. Copy and paste it exactly as I posted

Comment: Alright I think its okay now. Thanks for the help sir! Cheers~

Comment: Cool! Welcome and good luck!