# Synaptic touchpad on laptop not working after update 14.10

Tags: 14.10, touchpad, modprobe

I am having exactly the same problem with the touchpad after upgrading to 14.10, a solution was suggested in [Synaptic touchpad on laptop not working after update](https://askubuntu.com/questions/505265/synaptic-touchpad-on-laptop-not-working-after-update/591565?noredirect=1#comment822583_591565)

the manual solution of executing always works:

```
sudo modprobe -r psmouse
sudo modprobe psmouse proto=imps
```

but unfortunately I cannot make it permanent. I created the file **psmouse.conf** as it was suggested but the error remains, the touchpad is not working after rebooting. I have to plug a USB mouse and manually run in a terminal

```
sudo modprobe -r psmouse
sudo modprobe psmouse
```

This time I didn't include the parameters to check if the options would be taken from the file and it seems like it does, the touchpad works perfectly after those commands. But I don't understand why those options are not taken during the booting phase.

Finally I decided to add these two lines to the rc.local, but I dont like this workaround...

any idea why the settings in psmouse.cong are not taked during the booting phase?

thanks a lot. Jose

Comment: Is the `psmouse` loaded during boot at all?

Comment: yes, I just removed the two lines in the rc.local and restarted. The USB mouse works but the touchpad doesnt. I need to run the commands I said in order to get it work. It seems like the module psmouse gets loaded but it doesnt get the parameters set in the /etc/modprobe.d/psmouse.cfg .... as it should do in my opinion...