# Ubuntu 14.04 Touchpad not recognized and not working

Tags: 14.04, touchpad

After rebooting, my touchpad stopped working, thought it had been working previously. I also tried [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/262287/synaptic-touchpad-on-laptop-not-working/262364#262364).

This is the result from `xinput list`:

```
⎡ Virtual core pointer                      id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ Logitech USB Optical Mouse                id=13   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎣ Virtual core keyboard                     id=3    [master keyboard (2)]
    ↳ Virtual core XTEST keyboard               id=5    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=6    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Fujitsu FUJ02E3                           id=7    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Video Bus                                 id=8    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Fujitsu FUJ02B1                           id=9    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=10   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ FJ Camera                                 id=11   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ AT Translated Set 2 keyboard              id=12   [slave  keyboard (3)]
```

Also `cat /proc/bus/input/devices` doesn t show `SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad` anywhere