# Synaptics Touchpad Not working On Lenovo Ideapad

Tags: touchpad, lenovo, synaptics, ideapad

Since upgrading to 14.04 my Synaptic Touchpad no longer works. The only thing that seems to get it working was following these [instructions](https://askubuntu.com/questions/262287/synaptic-touchpad-on-laptop-not-working/262364)

The problem is after reboot the touchpad no longer works even though I have created a file:

```
/etc/modprobe.d/psmouse.conf
```

with the following contents:

```
options psmouse proto=imps
```

My USB logitech mouse works fine and so does the touchscreen though I would like to disable that. When I go to System Settings/Mouse & Touchpad there are no options for the touchpad.

My system also has a touchscreen if that is any help.

Some system details:

```
$ xinput --list

⎡ Virtual core pointer                      id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ Logitech USB Receiver                     id=9    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ ELAN Touchscreen                          id=10   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ PS/2 Synaptics TouchPad                   id=14   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎣ Virtual core keyboard                     id=3    [master keyboard (2)]
    ↳ Virtual core XTEST keyboard               id=5    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=6    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Video Bus                                 id=7    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=8    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Lenovo EasyCamera                         id=11   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Ideapad extra buttons                     id=12   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ AT Translated Set 2 keyboard              id=13   [slave  keyboard (3)]
```

and `cat /proc/bus/input/devices`

```
I: Bus=0011 Vendor=0002 Product=0001 Version=0000
N: Name="PS/2 Synaptics TouchPad"
P: Phys=isa0060/serio1/input0
S: Sysfs=/devices/platform/i8042/serio1/input/input6
U: Uniq=
H: Handlers=mouse0 event3 
B: PROP=0
B: EV=7
B: KEY=70000 0 0 0 0
B: REL=3
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried booting Ubuntu 14.10 Utopic Unicorn Beta 2 live to see if it is fixed in Utopic? If so, you might want to just wait for Utopic Unicorn later this month. I know that Utopic fixes many, many hardware bugs and doesn't add very many new features. This is why people are calling it "the boring update".

Comment: No I have not but will give it a try and report back. Thanks

Comment: Still not working even in Vivid... In many cases, it is initially detected as a touchpad, but after at trying to use multiple fingers the driver fails, throws an error, and then reloads as a standard PS/2 device.