# Cursor doesn't move after upgrade 14.04 to 14.10

Tags: touchpad, gui, cursor

After upgrading my system from 14.04 to 14.10 I have a problem with my touchpad: cursor moves.. hm.. from time to time. I mean when I try to move it in 90% cases it doesn't happen. But, if I click the touchpad and move it simultaneously - it moves. Where should I look to solve this issue? 
Laptop: Lenovo E440

Comment: I'm having the same trouble with my Lenovo Thinkpad E540.

Comment: UPDATE: The usual "trackpad doesn't work" fixes and workarounds are not effective. (tinkering with the psmouse module, playing with the options in the gpointing-device-settings application, turning on and off syndaemon with various options.) There may be a synclient setting or two that helps but I haven't found it yet.

Comment: By the way, several Ubuntu updates ago the issue disappeared. Not sure which of the packages is responsible for it.

Answer (score 7):

Found a fix here: [Synaptic touchpad on laptop not working](https://askubuntu.com/questions/262287/synaptic-touchpad-on-laptop-not-working)

In short:

```
sudo modprobe -r psmouse
sudo modprobe psmouse proto=imps
```

Answer (score 2):

I have the same problem. And I found a solution.

`synclient FingerLow=0`

Comment: Could you please clarify your answer? Where does one need to enter your text to get the desired result? Maybe also add **why** this will help in this situation. Please click [edit](http://askubuntu.com/posts/548808/edit) below your answer to add the information.

Comment: @fox0001 I'll mention that synclient is the command-line utility for querying and setting Synaptics driver options. The GNOME graphical equivalent is gpointing-device-settings (which is usually not installed by default in Ubuntu). The [man page for synclient](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/lucid/man1/synclient.1.html) describes how to query the device to determine which options are available to set.

Comment: 4 years later... Ubuntu 18.10... this just sorted me out - Many thanks!