# ASUS TP550L Touchscreen not working in Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, touchpad, touchscreen

After installing Ubuntu 14.04 I had problem with my touchpad,
it was not working until I found the following solution described
here: [Synaptic touchpad on laptop not working](https://askubuntu.com/questions/262287/synaptic-touchpad-on-laptop-not-working)

As mentioned in the link above, I used the following commands:

```
sudo modprobe -r psmouse
sudo modprobe psmouse proto=imps
```

then I created the file `/etc/modprobe.d/psmouse.conf` with the following content...

```
options psmouse proto=imps
```

now both my touchscreen and touchpad don't work.

this is the list of my input devices:

```
⎡ Virtual core pointer                      id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ USB Optical Mouse                         id=12   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ ETPS/2 Elantech Touchpad                  id=15   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎣ Virtual core keyboard                     id=3    [master keyboard (2)]
↳ Virtual core XTEST keyboard               id=5    [slave  keyboard (3)]
↳ Power Button                              id=6    [slave  keyboard (3)]
↳ Video Bus                                 id=7    [slave  keyboard (3)]
↳ Video Bus                                 id=8    [slave  keyboard (3)]
↳ Sleep Button                              id=9    [slave  keyboard (3)]
↳ Asus WMI hotkeys                          id=13   [slave  keyboard (3)]
↳ AT Translated Set 2 keyboard              id=14   [slave  keyboard (3)]
```