# New Ubunt 15.10 Install - Mouse issues, Highlight, Copy/Paste, Left click

Tags: usb, keyboard, mouse, touchpad, ubuntu-gnome

So,

I recently installed Ubuntu Gnome 15.10 on my older Asus K50IJ to do some web development and have a dedicated shell environment on the go.

I have noticed some very odd mouse behaviors including when highlighting text in any application, the mouse whether the touchpad or external usb wireless is very touchy.

Behavior:

- When attempting to drag mouse across text with mouse, selection jumps to original position. This occurs with touchpad, external usb wireless and even when using the keyboard to highlight text.
- When left-clicking items with touchpad or external usb wireless, mouse pointer returns to center of screen.

I am assuming this is not a mouse related issue as the keyboard also has an issue, i haven't been able to isolate the issue.

I have installed the video drivers for my GMA4500 by using the Intel Graphics Installer for Linux. There has been no change in the behavior however.

All behaviors are intermittent.

Please advise.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is similar to this post [Synaptic touchpad on laptop not working](https://askubuntu.com/questions/262287/synaptic-touchpad-on-laptop-not-working). The solution is shown below

This seems to be a bug in 15,10. A simple fix would be unloading the mouse driver and load it again like this:

```
sudo modprobe -r psmouse
sudo modprobe psmouse proto=imps
```

This only keeps the touchpad working on this session. To make it permanent one can create a file like /etc/modprobe.d/psmouse.conf (you can choose the name you want, but you must keep the extension) with the following content:

```
options psmouse proto=imps
```