# ASUS ZenBook UX305 touchpad not working

Tags: system-installation, touchpad

there is no cursor and touchpad not working. I was trying to install Ubuntu 15.10
but I could not even finish installation without it...
Anyone here to help?
Someone posted this problem on the same computer 2months ago, but I didn't see it solved

Answer (score 0):

It seems this may already have a kernel available and should be included in 4.5 kernel as well:

http://bugzilla.kernel.org/show_bug.cgi?id=108581

You may be able to install using usb mouse + Ubuntu 15.10 and then apply the kernel available via comment #24 of the link (assuming that its a UX305**CA**). You would then need to continue using that kernel for use of the touchpad.

Ubuntu 16.04 for instance will ship with 4.4 kernel so even for that you'd have a problem for install. Possibly 16.10 will finally make things easier that way here or possibly something like 16.04.1 if it includes kernel update.

Comment: Why do you think 16.04 will be shipped with 4.4 kernel?

Comment: @Pilot6

http://www.phoronix.com/scan.php?page=news_item&px=Ubuntu-16.04-Linux-4.4-1

Comment: @Pilot6 [OMG Ubuntu](http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2015/10/ubuntu-16-04-release-schedule-release-schedule-date-xenial-xerus)

Answer (score 0):

I have an ASUS UX305FA my touchpad was working fine during the installation of ubuntu.
It worked fine for another hour then something happend, my pointer disappeared and I could not use my touchpad anymore. I am trying to understand what happened but I cannot get a clue.

This post helped to mitigate the problem: [Synaptic touchpad on laptop not working](https://askubuntu.com/questions/262287/synaptic-touchpad-on-laptop-not-working)

Now I can use the touchpad as a mouse but commands made by two fingers are not working. It works like a mouse and not like a touchpad.

The funny thing is that if I access the system as Guest the touchpad works properly.
I installed ubuntu **16.04 beta 2** and my **xinput** output is:

```
Virtual core pointer                        id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
 ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer               id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
 ↳ ETPS/2 Elantech Touchpad                 id=12   [slave  pointer  (2)]
```

if I type: **cat /proc/bus/input/devices**
I get:

```
I: Bus=0011 Vendor=0002 Product=000e Version=0000
N: Name="ETPS/2 Elantech Touchpad"
P: Phys=isa0060/serio4/input0
S: Sysfs=/devices/platform/i8042/serio4/input/input12
U: Uniq=
H: Handlers=mouse0 event6
B: PROP=5
B: EV=b
B: KEY=e420 10000 0 0 0 0
B: ABS=661800011000003
```