# How do I make my Dell XPS 13 Developer Edition touchpad work correctly in 18.04?

Tags: touchpad, dell, 18.04, xps

I've got the Dell XPS 13 Developer Edition laptop, of which I am a big fan. My touchpad works in 17.10 without a problem, but when I boot into 18.04, I get bad behaviour. I can move the pointer, but it's jerky, and just stops following my touchpad movement.

It works fine when I boot to a 17.10 USB key. Using a USB mouse also works fine. The problem occurs when I have a USB mouse connected or not.

I get the same behaviour when I start an Xorg session or a Wayland session, so my guess is that the problem is at a lower level, like the kernel.

Comment: I wonder why this would be an issue only on 18.04, but can you try blacklisting the "psmouse" module? `echo "blacklist psmouse" >/etc/modprobe.d/xps13mouse.conf && update-initramfs -u && reboot`

Comment: That stopped the mouse entirely.

Comment: I think this is a good sign, because you shouldn't be using the psmouse driver. Is your touchpad listed by `sudo libinput list-devices`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Synaptic touchpad on laptop not working](https://askubuntu.com/questions/262287/synaptic-touchpad-on-laptop-not-working)

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem (xps13, update to 18.04) and did the same as in [Synaptic touchpad on laptop not working](https://askubuntu.com/questions/262287/synaptic-touchpad-on-laptop-not-working):

```
sudo modprobe -r psmouse
sudo modprobe psmouse proto=imps
```

Answer (score 1):

This fixed my Dell XPS (Cyprus touchpad) issue on Mate Ubuntu 18.04.  I saw the issue in both Mate and regular Ubuntu.

```
sudo apt-get install xserver-xorg-core
sudo apt-get install xserver-xorg-input-synaptics
sudo apt-get install xserver-xorg-input-all
```

Then reboot

Answer (score 0):

I installed `xf86-input-synaptics` and I made some changes to `/etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/70-synaptics.conf`.

```
sudo apt-get install xserver-xorg-input-synaptics
sudo cp /usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/70-synaptics.conf /etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/
```

You can check what settings Synaptics with:

```
synclient -l
```

and you can try some settings like:

```
synclient TapButton1=1
```

I think this is not perfect, but now I can sleep well.

Ref:

- [Ubuntu Forum / Ubuntu 16.04 touchpad not working](https://ubuntuforums.org/archive/index.php/t-2322413.html)
- [Arch Linux / Synaptics タッチパッド (Japanese)](https://wiki.archlinux.jp/index.php/Synaptics_%E3%82%BF%E3%83%83%E3%83%81%E3%83%91%E3%83%83%E3%83%89)