# Dell XPS Touchpad not detected after upgrade to 18.04

Tags: 18.04, touchpad, dell, synaptics

I recently installed Ubuntu 18.04 on my Dell XPS laptop. From the get-go, the touchpad was finnicky, often stalling, and really unusable. I found that [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1031941/858855) helped to resolve the basic problem, and movement with the touchpad now works smoothly, no issue with basic functionality. Great!

However, it still does not does not do two-finger scrolling, which is *super* useful on a laptop. I really miss it. I've been trying to figure out how to fix it, but there is no "two-finger scroll" option in `System Settings > Devices > Mouse & Touchpad`. In fact, there is no `Touchpad` section at all, and here is the output from `xinput`:

```
⎡ Virtual core pointer                      id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ ImPS/2 Generic Wheel Mouse                id=13   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎣ Virtual core keyboard                     id=3    [master keyboard (2)]
    ↳ Virtual core XTEST keyboard               id=5    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=6    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Video Bus                                 id=7    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=8    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Sleep Button                              id=9    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Laptop_Integrated_Webcam_1.3M:            id=10   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Dell WMI hotkeys                          id=11   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ AT Translated Set 2 keyboard              id=12   [slave  keyboard (3)]
```

I'm not very knowledgeable about this, but it appears to me that the touchpad has not been detected. Any thoughts on how to troubleshoot this?

Thanks!

Comment: I'm having the same issue and I have no idea how to fix it.