# Lenovo IdeaPad Yoga 13 - touchpad not working / broken, subsequent keyboard and touchscreen issues

Tags: keyboard, xorg, touchpad, lenovo, touchscreen

I recently installed Ubuntu 16.04 on my 5 year old Lenovo and immediately my touchpad didn't work. I looked around and found a solution (can't find the link) which told me to do this:

```
sudo apt-get install aptitude
sudo aptitude update
sudo aptitude install xserver-xorg-input-synaptics
```

`aptitude` told me that a bunch of other `xserver-xorg` items would be removed to deal with the dependencies (apologies but I did not write down which ones though there were about 10 of them all related to `xserver-xorg`), and after installing and rebooting, my touchpad, keyboard and touchscreen all worked. I rebooted again the other day and now only my touchpad works.

I've looked online for other solutions, but none of the ones I've looked at have been helpful. I was thinking it might just be a case of reinstalling all the `xserver-xorg` packages that I uninstalled, but I'm not sure how to go about this since there are so many of them. Also any deeper insight into why my touchpad wouldn't work would be appreciated - it used to do the same thing to me on Windows until I installed the Synaptics drivers.

**EDIT:** The mouse and keyboard which I plugged in to my laptop were also not recognised.

**EDIT #2:** I ran `sudo apt-get install xserver-xorg-input-all` and now I'm right back where I started - touchpad not working, everything else fine.

Comment: So this was on a fresh install? I suggest booting from a Live USB, which should reproduce the original situation with the touchpad, to see (and save for reference) the packages involved.

Comment: Also, test 18.04. You might be lucky and everything just works out of the box!

Comment: @Ratler So actually 18.04 had the same problem as well as a bunch of others so I installed 16.04 instead. Booting from USB could be a good idea though

Comment: Try what I suggested [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1070524/lenovo-yoga-13-touchpad-not-working-in-ubuntu-18-04) to fix your scrolling.

Answer (score 0):

I followed [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/262287/synaptic-touchpad-on-laptop-not-working) which solved the issue, though I can't scroll as of yet. Weird that this bug is still an issue after 5 years.