# Lenovo-yoga 13 touchpad not working in Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: mouse, touchpad, lenovo

I tried the solution [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/262287/synaptic-touchpad-on-laptop-not-working/262364#262364)

`sudo modprobe -r psmouse && sudo modprobe psmouse proto=imps` works to enable the touchpad during the current session.

However, the permanent solution (create file in `/etc/modprobe.d/psmouse.conf`) does not work.

Comment: I found a solution, instead of `options psmouse proto=imps` in the psmouse.conf file it should say: `psmouse proto=imps`. I'd rather prefer to put this as a comment in the original question, but I don't have enough privileges.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got it working by creating the following /etc/rc.local file entry.

```
#!/bin/bash
rmmod psmouse&&modprobe psmouse
```

Don't forget to update permissions.

```
chmod 755 /etc/rc.local
```

This solution also retains the OS configured mouse settings such as natural and two finger scrolling.